# how to find two groups and replace one with the other one using regexp?

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have a situation where I need to find 2 groups in some text and replace `$1` with `$2`.

I'm not sure it's possible. Also, I don't want to use php but simple search and replace.

See [here](http://regexr.com?300ru) or see this text:

```
<li>
<div>
    <a href="/video/testimonials/video-477" class="shadow"></a>
</div><div class="videoTb_title">Kevin Austin</div>
</li>
```

What I want is to find `video-477` and replace it with `Kevin Austin`.

This is just an example, I have more li's that have different names and video id's

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: The structure is always the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming /video/testimonials is actually part of most of your urls, you can capture and replace with the following regex:

```
(<a[^"]+\"/video/testimonials/)([^"]+)(\".+</a>\r?\n?.*?videoTb_title\"\>)([^<]+)</div>
```

to be replaced with

```
$1$4$3$4$5</div>
```

Keep in mind, your example accepted: href="/video/testimonials/Kevin Austin", which might be considered bad practice to use whitespace in urls.

Answer (score 0):

We would really need more information about the structure of all of the elements to make sure that we could produce a regex that always worked.

Here is an example of a regex that would work for your example:

```
/video/testimonials/([^"]+)
```

"video-477" would then be stored in $1.

Comment: then `le">(.+)<` would grab the `Kevin Austin` and store it in `$2`. But how do i find them both in the same search?

Comment: Maybe using PHP DomDocument http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php is more effectiv.